# CSS selector with two classes on one element

Tags: css, class, css-selectors

How do I do a CSS selector that selects a div that has the class of `someButton` AND `current`?

```
.someButton .current { /* select current with the parent div of .someButton, correct? */
```

Please help me figure this out!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to concatenate it: `.someButton.current`.

With a space, it will be seen as "apply on any element with class `.current` which is nested in a parent element with class `.someButton`".

Answer (score 2):

Remove the whitespace

```
.someButton.current
```

Answer (score 0):

div.someButton.current { ... }